# Can't run Grails 4.0.1 cli with Java 11 - get null pointer error in stacktrace

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception, command-line-interface

I can't run the grails 4.0.1 command line to create a new app etc

My environment:

- Windows 10
- Java 11.0.5 JDK
- Grails 4.0.1
- Groovy v3.0.0-rc-1
- JAVA_HOME set (D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5)
- GRAILS_HOME set (D:\dev-binaries\grails\grails-4.0.1)
- GROOVY_HOME set (D:\dev-binaries\groovy\groovy-3.0.0-rc-1)

When I start a command line and try to start grails shell I get (ignoring the Java 11 reflection warning)

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:515)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:306)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:269)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

So now I am stuck - I can't the grails shell and can't run a 'create-app' script

grails -version only seems to work and reports this on command line

```
| Grails Version: 4.0.1
| JVM Version: 11.0.5
```

How can I resolve this? I'd rather not have to revert all my versions if avoidable.

Comment: just peeked at code base and its here ```     String profileName = applicationConfig.get(BuildSettings.PROFILE) ?: getSetting(BuildSettings.PROFILE, String, DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME)
        this.profile = profileRepository.getProfile(profileName)```

Comment: looks like profileRepository is probably null - so calling getProfile () generates the NPE.  profileRepository is a declared local var but set with any initial value so something fails when its trying to set this value elsewhere.  Im using java 11 and get warnings about `Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1`  not sure if its failing because of this failure ?

Comment: I am not setup to test on Windows right now but on macOs I have been unable to reproduce the problem.  One thing that stands out is you are using Groovy 3.0.0-rc-1.  Do you see the same behavior when using Groovy 2.5.6?  If you can isolate a combo of items that leads to the problem, please report an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we can look into that.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: A useful data point would be to know if you create the app at http://start.grails.org/ and then use the grailsw and gradlew wrappers in the created project, do those work or do you get errors there too?

Comment: Hi jeff- sorry for delay been tied up all week.  I just tried with project started at start grails using gradle wrapper.  It also fails to build with error `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':configureChromeDriverBinary'.
> com.github.erdi.gradle.webdriver.repository.DriverUrlNotFoundException: Driver url not found for name: "chromedriver", version: "2.45.0", platform: "windows", bit: "64"
`

Comment: stacktrace shows `Caused by: com.github.erdi.gradle.webdriver.repository.DriverUrlNotFoundException: Driver url not found for name: "chromedriver", version: "2.45.0",
 platform: "windows", bit: "64"                                                                                                                     
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)                                                 
        at ...`.

Comment: interesting.  Still in same directory as downloader starter - tried to start grails again on command line and got `| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip`  waited a while whilst in resolved stuff.  Then reported a a trace on screen with `The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\will\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist:`

Comment: however, despite that it then reports its started the app with bootRun `Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
<=======<==========---> 83% EXECUTING [5m 14s]` and when i login to the browser i can connect to the generated shell application using chrome

Comment: if i cd to parent directory and try to start grails there it fails as before.  So starting grails at the command line must be reading the local directory on startup looking for something which sees in a project directory (build.gradle ?)  - but isnt there in  a non project parent directory

Comment: PS - i reset my environment variables to groovy 2.5.6  (from v3) - and restarted the cmd line.  I tried to run grails in the parent directory as before and it stall fails with the `| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:515)`  so its something a bit weirder than just the groovy version

Comment: i jest tried to clear my .gradle caches in my home directory and deleted the .gradle caches in the downloaded projects.  when i do that run `gradle build` then the project fails to build with `> Task :configureChromeDriverBinary FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':configureChromeDriverBinary'.
> com.github.erdi.gradle.webdriver.repository.DriverUrlNotFoundException: Driver url not found for name: "chromedriver", version: "2.45.0", platform: "windows", bit: "64"`.  This using gradle v5.6.2 and groovy 2.5.6 set in my env

Comment: One last comment.  I wiped my .gradle, .grails, .groovy, .m2 caches from home directory.  If i go to a new directory and type grails at the cmd line it starts with no error.  if I cd back into my intellij projects folder (which only has sub directories in it) and try that i get this null pointer error.  there are no other files here than sub projects directory folders.  done a `dir /a:h` to check as well.  so really weird.

Comment: i have just created a new app using grails create-app ... in this new directory.  when i cd into that app directory and do `grails run-app` it runs but i get this warning `The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\will\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist:`

Comment: if instead i do a `gradle build` in the project directory the build fails with `> Task :configureChromeDriverBinary FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':configureChromeDriverBinary'.
> com.github.erdi.gradle.webdriver.repository.DriverUrlNotFoundException: Driver url not found for name: "chromedriver", version: "2.45.0", platform: "windows", bit: "64"` as before

Comment: tried to resolve the chromedriver issue but still fails. i checked my chrome and its v78.0.3904.108.    1) i downloaded the driver from `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.105/` and installed .exe on local folder.  2) added folder to my path  3) i created an environment variable `webdriver.chrome.driver` at the .exe download location on my drive.  4) i tweaked the build config to exact driver version i downloaded `webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver  '078.0.3904.105' //'2.45.0'  
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}`  5) gradle build still fails with exception

Comment: you can see this default app with build.gradle mods for chromedriver here `https://github.com/woodmawa/newGrails4App`  i've set the java 8, groovy v2.5.6 and created with grails 4.0.1

Answer (score 3):

We ran into a similar issue when upgrading to Grails 4.0.3.

Our issue was because our developers use Windows and it appeared that the appropriate binaries for Windows 64bit were not available.

We modified the `webdriverBinaries` section as follows:

```
webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver {
        version = '79.0.3945.36'
        if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT || Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
            architecture = 'X86'
        } else {
            architecture = 'X86_64'
        }
    }
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}
```